# Unable to debug using cheri-gdb debugger error: unsupported relocation type 0xe802

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to use cheriBSD and the cheri gdb debugger to compile code with cheri capabilities however I am unable to use the gdb debugger on any of my c files due to a BFD: unsupported relocation type 0xe802 error? I'm not quite sure what that is, the c file should properly compile fine so I believe it is an issue with gdb but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

In the original gdb-cheri package we published, that relocation was not supported, and so you would see many errors of that form, but they were not fatal; GDB would continue on, just unable to interpret those specific relocations, so they should not have posed a problem. Since then we have shipped a newer version of the gdb-cheri package which does support that relocation, but that was built in October 2022 in time for the CheriBSD 22.12 release in December 2022. So it sounds to me like you are running an old (and thus no longer supported) version of CheriBSD rather than the latest version at the time you answered this question. Though even then its should have worked if you ignore the initial spew of error messages; more detail on what was broken would be helpful to resolve whatever issue you're having.

In future, StackOverflow is unlikely to be a useful place for you to get timely support. CHERI, Morello and CheriBSD are currently niche technologies that almost nobody on StackOverflow will have experience with. The official support channels for CheriBSD are listed in https://ctsrd-cheri.github.io/cheribsd-getting-started/support/index.html, and the Slack instance documented there is where we would advise you head.