# Unsupported relocation type error when debugging CHERI capabilities program with GDB

Tags: arm, gdb

I'm encountering an error message while trying to debug my CHERI capabilities program using GDB. When running the program through GDB, I receive the error 'BFD: unsupported relocation type 0xe802.' This error seems to be related to the Binary File Descriptor (BFD) library used by GDB. It occurs when my program, which utilizes CHERI capabilities, encounters an unsupported relocation type. I'm unsure about the specific cause of this error and how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions on how to address this problem would be greatly appreciated.

I have already tried updating my CHERI SDK and toolchain to the latest versions, but the issue persists.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76556276/unable-to-debug-using-cheri-gdb-debugger-error-unsupported-relocation-type-0xe8/